# Celery error: result.get(timeout=5) times out even though result.status is SUCCESS

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery

I have an API that starts a celery task via `result = task.delay()` and then waits for a result via `result.get(timeout=5)`. I am currently writing a performance test, which executes this task really often. It works fine on my local machine, but shows weird behavior when executed inside our development VM. After about 90-92 executions, `result.get(timeout=5)` times out, even though the task succeeds within several milliseconds.

It almost seems as if the result goes missing in the result backend. I am using RabbitMQ as a message broker for both directions:

```
celery_broker_url = pyamqp://guest@localhost//
celery_result_backend = rpc://
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how to investigate this issue further? Is it possible to check if the result is passed into the result backend? The RabbitMQ log doesn't show any entry:

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2019-01-30 16:49:24 UTC, end at Thu 2019-01-31 14:01:46 UTC. --
-- No entries --
```

Here is the complete stacktrace in case it helps:

```
[2019-01-31 13:56:42,313] ERROR in app: Exception on /user/lmhsqs/register [POST]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 255, in _wait_for_pending

    on_interval=on_interval):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 54, in drain_events_until

    raise socket.timeout()

socket.timeout



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise

    raise value

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request

    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 66, in wrapper

    response = function(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 122, in wrapper

    response = function(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 293, in wrapper

    return function(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 42, in wrapper

    response = function(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/parameter.py", line 219, in wrapper

    return function(**kwargs)

  File "/mynedata/lib/api/apicalls.py", line 73, in register_user

    res_to_return = result.get(timeout=5)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 224, in get

    on_message=on_message,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 188, in wait_for_pending

    for _ in self._wait_for_pending(result, **kwargs):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 259, in _wait_for_pending

    raise TimeoutError('The operation timed out.')

celery.exceptions.TimeoutError: The operation timed out.

127.0.0.1 - - [2019-01-31 13:56:42] "POST /user/lmhsqs/register HTTP/1.1" 500 388 5.050726

[2019-01-31 13:56:47,374] ERROR in app: Exception on /user/lmhsqs/login [POST]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 255, in _wait_for_pending

    on_interval=on_interval):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 54, in drain_events_until

    raise socket.timeout()

socket.timeout



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise

    raise value

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request

    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 66, in wrapper

    response = function(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 122, in wrapper

    response = function(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 293, in wrapper

    return function(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 42, in wrapper

    response = function(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/parameter.py", line 219, in wrapper

    return function(**kwargs)

  File "/mynedata/lib/api/apicalls.py", line 123, in login_user

    res = result.get(timeout=5)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 224, in get

    on_message=on_message,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 188, in wait_for_pending

    for _ in self._wait_for_pending(result, **kwargs):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 259, in _wait_for_pending

    raise TimeoutError('The operation timed out.')

celery.exceptions.TimeoutError: The operation timed out.
```

Comment: Is it deployed on cloud?

Comment: Nope, it's a local vagrant VM using a ubuntu 18.04 image. RabbitMQ version is 3.6.10, Python 3.6.7

Comment: What information do you see when you execute your worker(s)? Is `rpc://` shown as a result backend? Or is it showing that the result backend is `disabled`?

Comment: If your result backend is enabled, do the followings. Before your `result.get(timeout=5)` try the following modifications: `result = your_task.s(params).delay()`     and next line: `result = AsyncResult(result.id)` and then use your `result.get(timeout=5)`

Comment: The result backend is enabled, I am trying your suggestion now, thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it fails with the same error @AiDa. Although not exactly the same behaviour: Now, the first API call fails with a timeout, then 90 calls succeed and after that, every result.get() times out.

Comment: Another thing that you can try is to set the broker and backend directly as follows: `app = Celery('celery_proj',
             broker='amqp://',
             backend='rpc://',
             include=['celery_proj.tasks'])`  The problem that you have -- as you mentioned -- is that your app cannot access the result backend.

Comment: I dont think the problem is the setup of the Celery object as it works for the first 90 calls. Maybe it's a RabbitMQ problem/bug...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187746/discussion-between-ai-da-and-gasp0de).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with celery or RabbitMQ but completely unrelated:

I started the celery worker using `os.subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(backend_cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`. Turns out that subprocess.PIPE pipe will be full at some point (I think after 2^16 characters), at which point my celery worker got stuck trying to write to the pipe, and thus stopped writing results to the result backend. This means the timeout I was seeing was valid.

I do not understand why result.status showed 'SUCCESS' after the timeout though.

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting up correct `backend` (instead of `result_backend`) fixed the issue.
I setup like this:
`app = Celery('tasks', broker=BROKER_URL, backend=BACKEND_URL)`

Also, make sure the message broker is running.